# Websocket is not sending data to all clients

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Good day,

I'm using node.js with https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql mysql package.

I have a script here that sends all connected clients their data (at least it's supposed to)

```
for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++)
{
    sql.query("SELECT coins FROM users_steam WHERE steamid="+clients[i].ID,function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        var bal = rows[0].coins;

        clients[i].send(JSON.stringify({
            'type':'roll',
            'roundid':ROUND,
            'places':r,
            'wait':WAIT,
            'roundtime':RollTime,
            'balance':bal
        }));
        clients[i].balRefreshes=0;

    });
}
```

Though the problem is, I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined`, which means that the id is not assigned correctly. Am I supposed to execute the queries in order or do something else in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem that I can see is that since your DB call is async and will get called at a later time, the variable "i" will be different from its value in the select query.

for example, try running this code in your console:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(i)
        }, 1000);
    }
```

You could try this instead:

```
clients.forEach(function(client, i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: yeah I just noticed that nodejs is actually async.. But how could I do it then?